# how to get anonymous event arg in solidity?

Tags: events, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm starting to use anonymous events so i wrote a very simple contract just to see how it works and the problem is when I deploy my contract with a simple event i can get the arg of the events but when i make it anonymous, I can't access them.

the contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
contract Lock {

   event DataStored(address admin, uint256 indexed data) anonymous;
   uint256 data;
   function storeData(uint256 data) external {
      data = data;
      emit DataStored(msg.sender, data);

   }
}
```

the deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  

  const Lock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Lock");
  const lock = await Lock.deploy();

  await lock.deployed();

  console.log(
    ` deployed to ${lock.address}`
  );
  tx = await lock.storeData(10);
  const transactionReceipt = await tx.wait()
  console.log(transactionReceipt.events[0])

}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

event logs without anonymous keyword and with anonymous keyword are in the pictures.

[with anonymous keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyRfu.png)

[without anonymous keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjonx.png)